# libGDX particle effect: is it possible to reverse it?

Tags: animation, libgdx, particle-system

I'm working with libGDX particle effect system, and I have a following need: to reverse an effect in time. These effects look like scattering particles, appearing in a single spot, and what I need is exactly the opposite - particles appearing in random places around the central spot and gathering in the central spot. It all is the sprite animation, and it could be reversed, but how?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not supported, so you may have to write your own effect.

Comment: Maybe give https://talosvfx.com/ a try. Not sure if it supports exactly what you need bu it looks way more powerful than the default libgdx particle system.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can because the particle editor allows negative velocity plus I've done it in the particle editor.

1 set the velocity to -300 low to +300 high (or whichever)

2 particle size is zero to begin with (invisible), this allows the particle to move away from origin at appear at a radius

3 at the desired radiues, when you arrive, restore the size (become visible).

4 this point is when the velocity reverses heading back to the origin.

The point is that negative or positive velocity both head away from the origin, but as you interpolate between the two you reverse the course. As long as you are invisible (make the particle 0 size) then you appear at the radius and travel inwards.